# Prop-type warnings show `b` instead of component name

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have been trying to implement `prop-types` in my components for better documentation and error handling. However, when a warning is raised, the call stack contains letters in place of component names.

Ex:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `type` is marked as required in `b`, but its value is `undefined`.
in b (created by b)
in b (created by withI18nextTranslation(b))
in withI18nextTranslation(b) (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by c)
in c (created by LoginLayout)
in div (created by LoginLayout)
in LoginLayout (created by c)
in c (created by b)
in Switch (created by b)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (created by b)
in b
in I18nextProvider
in Provider
```

Of course, this is not ideal, as I cannot find out which component is having this issue.

My first thought was that it was somehow related to I18next, but even after deleting, the issue persists.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Variable letters are caused by minified code, not related to any component.

Comment: Is it minified code?

Comment: Ah, yes that may be the culprit. However, I'd like it to remain minified. Is there a way to handle prop checking prior to minifying?

Comment: Run in development mode where you dont minify? you should minify when deploying to production. During development you should instead not minify and setup sourcemaps so you can easily see where / what the issue is

Comment: That sounds like a much better workflow. I'll try it out! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep! You can search for examples where when mode === production another minify step is added to the compile process :)